# Wordpress ajax 500 error after php update

Tags: wordpress

I have upgraded my php version from 5.6 to 7.3 , after fixing the deprecated functions and test running the website i am stuck with an issue . I have a plugin from where i am getting a parking fee calculated and returned on the home page , i am sending the data through ajax and updating the form . For some reason the php 5.6 version was not showing me any error but when i update it to 7.3 , the ajax call always shows a http 500 error and i cant access the page where the script is written . This is the page that i am trying to send the data to using ajax :- https://textifly.co/thecarportandspa.com.au/wp-content/themes/car-port-spa/show_calculation.php
This only happens when i update the php version . Can anyone help me with this issue ?
The link to my website where the calculation is taking place: https://textifly.co/thecarportandspa.com.au/

Comment: Put these in your show_calculations.php to check for errors at the top of the page after <?php

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: i tried doing that but the problem is , the ajax call is not being able to access the page at all . Thats why its throwing a 500 internal error in the console , but it used to access the page in the 5.6 php version of the server after the update to 7.3 , suddenly the page is inaccessible which causes this error .